# Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey @match for a url with different possible extensions with regex

Tags: regex, tampermonkey

I'm trying to make a script that activates on amazon. I use multiple amazons though (.NL, .DE, .CO.UK etc) and I would like to use a regex to pick that up, so I can visit any website that starts with `https://www.amazon.` and have the script activate.

I wrote this regex for the @match rule in the header;

```
((https?):\/\/)?(\w+)\.(amazon)\.(?P<extension>\w+(\.\w+)?)(\/.*)?
```

According to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YD2XzY/1), the regex is correct and should pick up on strings like `https://www.amazon.de`, but the Tampermonkey script (in both Chrome and Safari) is not activating when I visit any amazon websites.

According to the Tampermonkey documentation it should support regex in @match, so why is it not working? Did I make a mistake in my regex after all? Is this regex too complex for the @match rule?

Comment: `@match` doesn't support regexps. Use `@include /https?://......../` or simply use the magic `tld` keyword like `@include https://www.amazon.tld/*`

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the magic keyword! It would be a perfect answer to my question if you'd like to write one @wOxxOm.